# Fail to load cpp function in parallel computing

Tags: c++, r, parallel.foreach, r-package

I installed my own package `PrimeBayesMIR` in Windows HPC server to do parallel computing. I found that it works to call my cpp function outside of `foreach` loop;

```
> Run1Gibbs3_2_cpp
function (n, ninst, m, membership, Y, X_bag, hp_mu_beta1, hp_a, 
    hp_b, hp_g_beta, hp_pi, hp_inv_Sig_beta, beta1, sig2_error, 
    delta) 
{
    .Call("_PrimeBayesMIR_Run1Gibbs3_2_cpp", PACKAGE = "PrimeBayesMIR", 
        n, ninst, m, membership, Y, X_bag, hp_mu_beta1, hp_a, 
        hp_b, hp_g_beta, hp_pi, hp_inv_Sig_beta, beta1, sig2_error, 
        delta)
}
<bytecode: 0x00000000152761b0>
<environment: namespace:PrimeBayesMIR>
```

However, when the function is called within `foreach` loop, it gives me this error

```
Error in { : 
  task 1 failed - ""_PrimeBayesMIR_Run1Gibbs3_2_cpp" not available for .Call() for package "PrimeBayesMIR""
```

Do you have any idea to handle this kind of problem? I couldn't find any solution so far. Thanks for any comments on this.

Comment: Can you show us the `useDynLib` line from your package's `NAMESPACE`?

Comment: @RalfStubner Hi, thanks for your attention on this. Do you mean the file `NAMESPACE`? If so, there's no such line, unfortunately. Please correct me if I misunderstand your comment

Comment: Are you using Rcpp? It can really help with developing C++ for R. Anyway, it might help to add `.packages = "PrimeBayesMIR"` to the `foreach` call.

Comment: @RalfStubner Okay. I'll try that first. I missed that. Also, I generate another package and got what you told me; `useDynLib(PrimeBayesMIR2, .registration=TRUE)`. Do you see anything wrong here?

Comment: Did it work? the `useDynLib` line looks fine as long as you have the required registration code, which Rcpp does automatically.

Comment: @RalfStubner Sorry for late update, but it didn't work.

Comment: In that case I can only help if you can provide a [mcve].

Comment: @RalfStubner Okay, let me do this soon. I appreciate your attention on this.